# How to patch Apache mod-proxy 3.0.1 with 3.0.1-1.1?

Tags: 12.04, apache2, proxy, bug-reporting, patch

The command `$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-proxy-html` and then `$sudo service apache2 restart` fires:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 210 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax
error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/proxy_html.load: Cannot
load /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2 into server: /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2: cannot
open shared object file: No such file or directory Action 'configtest'
failed.
```

because 3.0.1 is buggy and apt-get offers only buggy version. So I am forced to manual install this [here](http://ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl/ubuntu//pool/universe/m/mod-proxy-html/libapache2-mod-proxy-html_3.0.1-1.1_i386.deb) but it ends up to Unpacked mode (seen with `$ dpkg -l|grep html`). Some discussion [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mod-proxy-html/+bug/964397) and more [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/quantal/i386/libapache2-mod-proxy-html/download).

The bug is also fixed in Debian: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=670633

How to fix this? How to apply the patch/fix now so I can proceed?

Comment: It seems to be a bug and the fix was released. [see this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mod-proxy-html/+bug/964397). So, it may be closed as off-topic

Comment: You can check [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/88848/61218) about getting the bug fixes. or you can discuss this on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)

Comment: Some chatting [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5212565#5212565).

Comment: FYI, this was fixed in Quantal. This post here however is a bug report. I will move this to the bugtrackers, and get an SRU filed

Comment: Please dpkg --remove the package, and then install it again. Paste all resulting output to a pastebin.

Comment: @izx http://pastie.org/4196383

Answer (score 2):

The Lord of Time solved this in a comment:

> FYI, this was fixed in Quantal. This post here however is a bug report. I will move this to the bugtrackers, and get an SRU filed

[The Lord Of Time July-3-12](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158909/how-to-patch-apache-mod-proxy-3-0-1-with-3-0-1-1-1#comment193641_158909)